# setuptools sdist ignore data_files

Tags: setuptools

According to docs https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/#data-files

setuptools will honor `data_files` configed in setup.py. But i can't make it work. This is my setup.py:

```
setup(
    name='booking_order',
    version=version,
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'booking_order': ['fake_backends/static/*',
                          'scripts/*',
                          '*.sample'],
    },
    data_files=[
        ('/etc/booking', ['etc/booking.conf'])
    ],
```

This is the project's file tree:

```
.
├── booking_order
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
├── etc
│   ├── booking.conf
├── README.md
├── setup.py
```

The behavior is, if i run `python setup.py install`, file `etc/booking.conf` will got installed to `/etc/booking`. But if i first `python setup.py sdist upload`, then `pip install booking_order`, there will be an error "error: can't copy 'etc/booking.conf': doesn't exist or not a regular file".
I checked `python setup.py sdist` doesn't include files in etc at all.

EDIT:

it seems this is the answer: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/521

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer it myself.

According to [pypa](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/521), and [non-package-data-files](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#non-package-data-files)。"Setuptools doesn't support installing data files to some arbitrary location on a user’s machine; this is a feature, not a bug."

If one need to install files to locations like /etc, /usr/share, eg, then he/she may use data_files flag from distutils, which feature is not totally cleaned up from setuptools. "Not totally cleaned up" means you need to add those files to MANIFEST.in manually, which is different as in distutils.

Of course, it will be better if one can manage these configuration files with rpm or deb package system. For me it's just a temporary solution to use pip here.